# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'start_time')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am facing this error when I update my last end time of last interval although it updates my state but not showing it in table

[image]

```
 const onEdit = (oldValue, newValue, row, column) => {
    const oldRows = props.row;
    console.log("BHai", props.row.length - 1);
    if (column.dataField === "end_time") {
      if (newValue < oldRows[row.interval + 1].start_time) {
        oldRows[row.interval][column.dataField] = newValue;
        const startTime = parseInt(row.start_time);
        const endTime = parseInt(row.end_time);
        props.onIntervalUpdate([startTime, endTime], row.interval);
        console.log("BHai1");
      } else if (oldRows[row.interval].interval === props.row.length - 1) {
        oldRows[row.interval][column.dataField] = newValue;
        const startTime = parseInt(row.start_time);
        const endTime = parseInt(row.end_time);
        props.onIntervalUpdate([startTime, endTime], row.interval);
        console.log("BHai2");
      } else {
        oldRows[row.interval][column.dataField] = oldValue;
        const startTime = parseInt(row.start_time);
        const endTime = parseInt(row.end_time);
        props.onIntervalUpdate([startTime, endTime], row.interval);
        console.log("BHai3");
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @dude_blag Please check before using start_time, row contains start_time or not.

Comment: Please have safety checks before you access the nested properties.

use `oldRows[row.interval + 1]?.start_time`

Apply the same thing in all places

Comment: thanks  both of you

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding [`Optional chaining (?.)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) during destructuring, as:

```
newValue < oldRows[row.interval + 1]?.start_time)
```

and

```
 const startTime = parseInt(row?.start_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out like this,

```
if (
        oldRows[row.interval].interval === props.row.length - 1 &&
        oldRows[row.interval].start_time
      )
```

working fine for me